# How to knit R markdown to word doc without code

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, output, knitr

I have some r markdown code that has graphs and tables as output.
I have tried to knit to Word but i don't know how to eliminate the code and remain with the output and titles only.

I tried this:

```
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: inline
bookdown::html_document2:
  code_folding: hide
```

but it only works for the HTML output. The word document output only has the graphs and no table. I want to output a full report with charts, tables and text but without code and warnings. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the level of individual code chunks you can use

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
...
```
````

You can also include a special code chunk in the beginning to make this the default:

````
```{r, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```
````

Comment: I have done that but now am getting only text. No tables

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example?